# Index of the tab that was closed

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane

Is it possible to get the index of the tab that is closed in JTabbedPane (in the context that's before the closing action)? In particular, when one closes a tab that is not in focus. I know we can use `tabPane.getSelectedIndex()` to get the index of the tab that is in focus. But it doesn't help in this case. I would really appreciate any help!!

Comment: How are you closing the tab? Can you show some code, preferably a valid [mcve]?

Comment: Why are you re-asking the same question as recent?